# Re-size web pages to suits visitors monitor resolution

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have designed a website site.
I would like to know if it is possible to make pages in my site re-size to suite the visitors' monitor resolution.

For example, I'm using my computer with 1024x768 resolution.
If I change my resolution to 800x600 I want my site to re-size to fit the screen resolution of 800x600.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design). Specifically look at [media queries](https://www.google.com/search?ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=media%20queries).

Answer (score 0):

This is called "dynamic" or "fluid" width, as opposed to setting a "fixed" width on the page. This is usually done with CSS, as opposed to PHP or JavaScript. Do some research on the subject on Google (search for "dynamic width web pages"). I found [this article](http://www.alteredimpressions.com/articles/web-design/web-page-width-dilemma/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the resolution, since not everybody uses their browser fullscreen; you want the document size.  There are ways to get that in plain javascript, but your best bet is to use a library like jquery, since that helps ensure your technique works cross-browser:

http://api.jquery.com/width/

But don't do that unless there is no other way to do what you want; first try using percentages in your CSS.  Setting sizes with js is messy.

Answer (score 0):

this is some key word for what your search

css grid system responsive/adaptative web

some links

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/quick-tip-different-layouts-for-different-widths/

http://speakerdeck.com/u/nathansmith/p/960-grid-system

http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/my-adaptive-grid/

http://webdesignledger.com/resources/responsive-web-design-templates-and-frameworks

[generator](http://grids.heroku.com/)